# Setting max-threads = 0 in tomcat shouldn't accept any further request from user but it's accepting. why?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

As per my understanding for below tomcat configuration -

```
tomcat:
    max-threads: 0
```

Server can process only **max-threads** value request concurrently, rest request will get queued.
If it's correct than server should not accept any request further if it's value is 0 but it's accepting other request also, why ?

Comment: Zero probably equals unlimited, as it's not a sane configuration number (or it's getting overridden by a different config parameter).

Answer (score 1):

0 value indicates unlimited threads, as adressed by the reference here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html

As well, if its not specified (which might be the case with 0 value), 200 will be set automatically.

And last:
if an executor is assigned to your tomcat, maxthread will be ignored.